# position doesn't work depends on getItemCount in RecyclerView (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, position, android-adapter

> override fun getItemCount(): Int {
> return ekipListesi.size
> }
>
> override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: KisilerVH, position: Int) {
> holder.binding.kisiAdiTextView.text = ekipListesi[position]
> println(itemCount)
> println(position)
> }

ItemCount return respectively 5 and 6 as I hope, but it creates one card for each called not 5 or 6.
So that position doesn't change 0,1,2,3,4 and 0,1,2,3,4,5

Position return just 0 in two case 1 times. I don't understand why this problem occured

I want to use create nested recyclerview. Parent works properly. However, "position" in childRV is doesn't work.

Comment: Nested RecyclerView position issues?

Answer (score 0):

```
class ParentAdapter(private val parentList: List<ParentItem>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ParentAdapter.ParentViewHolder>() {
    // ...

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return parentList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ParentViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val parentItem = parentList[position]
        
        // parent item views

        // child RecyclerView
        val childAdapter = ChildAdapter(parentItem.childItemList)
        holder.childRecyclerView.adapter = childAdapter
    }
}
```

---

```
class ChildAdapter(private val childList: List<ChildItem>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ChildAdapter.ChildViewHolder>() {
    // ...

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return childList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ChildViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val childItem = childList[position]
        
        // child item views
    }
}
```

---

[RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView)

[RecyclerView.Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter)